# VC++: Why does comparing int32_t to uint64_t require a higher warning level than comparing to uint32_t?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

```
auto negativeOneAsInt32 = -1i32;

auto zeroAsUint32 = 0ui32;
auto result1 = negativeOneAsInt32 < zeroAsUint32; // C4018
// result1 is "unexpectedly" false due to conversion to unsigned    
// Warned with "C4018 '<': signed/unsigned mismatch" at /W3 or higher

auto zeroAsUint64 = 0ui64;
auto result2 = negativeOneAsInt32 < zeroAsUint64; // C4388
// result2 is "unexpectedly" false due to conversion to unsigned    
// Only warned with "C4388 '<': signed/unsigned mismatch" at /Wall
```

Both comparisons contain the same bug for the same reason, but the VC++ compiler only warns about the second one under /Wall, while it warns about the first at /W3 (same message each time, but with different warning codes). Is there a specific reason for using two different codes and warning levels for what appears to be the same problem?

Comment: The behavior of these two is not really the same.  The second one doesn't get sign-extended.  Only because you are comparing to zero does sign extension not matter.

Comment: To compare this data, it will cast and there may be data loss. I think this difference comes from the difference in the size of the data relative to an int. You can see Compiler Warning (levels 3 and 4) C4244